# Custom filter in datatable with search button in jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using datatables plugin and i would like add custom search button (Go) to filter the grid which is populated by datatable.When User clicks go button selecting drug and organisation results should be filter

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to add multiple custom drop-down filters.

you can do it in this way.

```
//Call datatable
var table = table =  $('#tableId').DataTable({});

//Call on change event of dropdown and same thing can be done on Go button click
$('#drugDropdownId').on('change', function () {
    //Column number can be changed as per your need
    table.columns(2).search(this.value).draw();
});
```

Please check for [DataTable Search](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html)

FYI, please make sure that you're using proper and supported methods of your data-table version.